# What are the different powers used in Secret Invasion finale?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, secret-invasion

In the Secret Invasion TV series finale

> When Giah and Gravik fight with each other they use the power of different Superheroes and Villains.

What are the superheroes and villains whose power is shown as being used in the finale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List of Powers seen being used by Gravik and Giah during the Fight

**1. Extremis (Self Healing)**

[image]

**2. Arm of Groot**

**3. Arm of Abomination and Ears of Abomination**

[image]

**4. Arm of Drax**

**5. Ghost's Power to Phase through Object**

[image]

**6. Arm of Korg**

[image]

**7. Frost Beast Arm (Ice Arm)**

**8. Full Power of Captian Marvel**

[image]

**9. Arm of Thanos**

**10. Powers of Mantis**

**11. Telekinetic Powers of Ebony Maw**

Comment: There is also power of Hulk